# Submitting an iphone-only app to app store?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, app-store-connect

I am submitting my app to app store but it's only compatible with iphone and ipod. When I added the app in itunes connect it;s making me submit an ipad screenshot.

Is it mandatory for apps to be universal? How can I get around this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something other than programming.

Comment: You must enter iPhone *or* iPad screenshots. If your app is universal then you can add both

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In XCode  Target -> General -> Deployment Info -> Devices should be set to iPhone.

Comment: Even after following your steps, app is getting installed on simulator.

Comment: You have to select "Generic iOS Device" where you select simulators or devices for running.

Answer (score 2):

If your app is only supposed to support iPhone/iPod, **only upload iPhone screenshots**, don't upload iPad screenshots. Same works the other way around. The only time you should upload both is if your app is universal.

Answer (score 2):

It is not mandatory for apps to be Universal, nor is required to submit both iPhone and iPad screenshots, you can just submit your 3,5" and 4,0" iPhone screenshots.

If it's complaining because iPad screenshots are missing, you might want to check in XCode that your project isn't configured as Universal.