# Restrict app to just iPhone while publishing

Tags: ios, itunes

I had uploaded an app on iTunes. But it got rejected stating a couple of reasons:

```
Performance: App Completeness
Performance: Accurate Metadata
```

And from what I understood the issue was with the app not showing up as intended on the 12.9 inch iPad. But I had made my app for the iPhone itself and not for the iPad. And since iTunes was not allowing to submit the app without attaching a screenshot of the app in the 12.9 inch iPad also, I was forced to attach one.

How can I restrict my app to support just iPhone...?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294326/submitting-an-iphone-only-app-to-app-store

Comment: Thanks for the link @Matthew Vanlandingham. Do put this up as the answer so that I can accept it...:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submitting an iphone-only app to app store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294326/submitting-an-iphone-only-app-to-app-store)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, my answer kept getting posted as a comment so I'm just going to add this stuff here. Looks like you need to go XCode Target -> General -> Deployment Info -> Devices and set it as iPhone instead of universal.

[Submitting an iphone-only app to app store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294326/submitting-an-iphone-only-app-to-app-store)