# App rejected because of screenshot, what should I do now?

Tags: ios, iphone

I've always used my app's onboarding pages for screenshots for the previous versions and nothing was wrong. But this time apple rejected it and said the issue was:

> Guideline 2.3.3 - Performance - Accurate Metadata
>
> We noticed that your screenshots do not sufficiently reflect your app in use.
>
> Specifically, your screenshots do not display the actual app in use.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please revise your screenshots to ensure that they accurately reflect the app in use on the supported devices. For iPhone, you need a set of 5.5-inch display screenshots and for iPad, you need a set for 12.9-inch display. This set will be scaled appropriately down to other device sizes when viewed on the App Store in each territory.
>
> Note that 6.5-inch display assets for iPhone XS Max are optional, and can scale down to iPhone XR, iPhone XS, and iPhone X. Screenshots that include features like rounded corners or sensor housing should only be used for the 6.5-inch or 5.8-inch display.
>
> Resources
>
> For resources on creating great screenshots for the App Store, you may want to review the App Store Product Page information available on the Apple developer portal.
>
> Please ensure you have made any screenshot modifications using Media Manager. You should confirm your app looks and behaves identically in all languages and on all supported devices. Learn how to use Media Manager to add custom screenshots for each display size and localization.
>
> Please see attached screenshots for details.
>
> Since your App Store Connect status is Metadata Rejected, we do NOT require a new binary. To revise the metadata, visit App Store Connect to select your app and revise the desired metadata values. Once you’ve completed all changes, reply to this message in Resolution Center and we will continue the review.

What is my best option to get my app approved? My app doesn't support iPad but they seem to be demanding for iPad screenshots too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submitting an iphone-only app to app store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294326/submitting-an-iphone-only-app-to-app-store)

Comment: It is a standard reply, so it mentions the requirements for an iPad app. If your app is not universal then you don't need iPad screen shots. The answer to your question, "what should I do now?" Is clear; provide screen shots that show your app in use, not the on boarding screens.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced same rejection from apple.

In my case I was added so many pages/screen in application but not added screenshot in apple store.

So I added all other screenshot then my application got approved.

If you don't want your application available for ipad then don't add screenshot in ipad or you can do as follow :

```
In XCode Target -> General -> Deployment Info -> Devices should be set to iPhone.
```